# how to display the names or labels over a marker on google map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i tried using

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(geom.get(0)).title("hai how are bgdj");

map.addMarker(marker);
```

where **geom.get(0)** is the LatLng and **map** is google map

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(MELBOURNE)
                            .title("Melbourne")
                            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(geom.get(0)).title("hai how are bgdj");
map.addMarker(marker);
Marker mk = map.addMarker(marker);
mk.showInfoWindow();
```

where **geom.get(0)** is the LatLng and **map** is google map

thanks guys,
this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                 .position(currentLocation)
                 .title("Name")
                 .snippet("pranav")
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                 .fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.